# Confused why php code isn't working as expected. Using if( x and y) {}

Tags: php

So this was my original post about what I'm trying to do: [PHP, delete files in a specific directory with a specific extension as long as it's over (10) minutes old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914466/php-delete-files-in-a-specific-directory-with-a-specific-extension-as-long-as-i?noredirect=1#comment121792696_68914466).
But to sum it up, basically create a script that goes through a directory, filter by files with x file extension (in this case .mobileconfig) and then check whether it's a file (and then I want it to check if the last modified date was less than 1 day, except it doesn't check, it just ignores it. I think) then if both those statements are true, then delete the file.
Here's what I have:

```
$files = glob('./generated/*.mobileconfig');
$filelastmodified = filemtime($files);

foreach($files as $file){

  if(is_file($file) && ((time() - $filelastmodified) > 24*3600)) {

    unlink($file); // delete file

  }

}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, besides that it's not considering the second part, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `var_dump(is_file($file), time() - $filelastmodified, 24*3600);`

Comment: Is there a reason you posted this question again two hours later? I can’t tell what is different.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that, but if I do `if(var_dump(is_file($file) && ((time() - $filelastmodified) > 24*3600))) {unlink file};` it works, but it also writes "bool(true)" to the page. could I get rid of that?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I changed how I went about doing it so that it looked for .mobileconfig files rather than just deleting everything, and this just worked except for the "check that x amount of time has passed since file was last modified" which is really all I needed to figure out

Comment: Generally speaking, please just edit your original question if it is along the same line. You can either update it or append to it depending on how the conversation is flowing. If for some reason you need to post a new question, unless you want an answer to your original related question, please just delete it. If someone has answered your original question with a semi-valid attempt, even if it doesn’t work, it is considered rude to delete it then.

Comment: @ChrisHaas oh okay sorry

Answer (score 0):

The function `filemtime` must be called on a *single* filename, not on a complete array of filenames.